# Strategy pattern with Async c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, asp.net

My question is

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void HandleRequest(int i);
}

public class Class1 : IFoo
{
    public void HandleRequest(int i)
    {
        if(i == 1) // just for example
        {
            //In this case i forced to call for async method
            // await DoSomething();
        }
        //but in all other cases sync implementation
    }
}

public class Class2 : IFoo
{
    public void HandleRequest(int i)
    {
        //here sync impelementation
    }
}
```

In this case in Class1 base on the condition when i == 1 i should call for async operation, but make all methods due to one condition - async it's something a bit of boolshit. What do you make of it?

Comment: Can you make your question a little clearer?  Also, what does "boolshit" mean?  Is that like "fake news?"  In general, you can't choose between sync and async at runtime, though you can make an async call block (effectively making it synchronous) by simply asking the returned Task for its `Result` member.

Comment: For me this code smells a bit, because due to one condition in one method i should make method async down to all hiararchy. And from other sync implementation Return something like Task.FromResult

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what the purpose of the code is.  In any case, whatever it is that you're trying to do, I'm pretty sure you can do it without the Strategy pattern.

Comment: If you start using Async - accept that it will spread around your codebase as zombie virus. This is by design. If you don't want to accept  - use only synchronous methods.

Comment: Same way you can complain about "my methods return `int` but under some condition I need return `string`". Asynchronous method need to return type of `Task<T>` or `Task`.

Comment: Why not just add a HandleRequestAsync?

Answer (score 2):

You have two clear choices here:

1. Make `HandleRequest`, and all methods that call it, and in turn that call them etc, async. Problem solved.
2. [Follow the instructions in this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/7122) in order to let the async call complete and then return the result from that.

If you have just one async method in your code base and you don't need it to behave asynchronously, go for option 2. Otherwise, [embrace the zombie virus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and adopt option 1.

Comment: Another option is Rx.NET. Tasks and asyncs can be wrapped up into a different way of doing things.

Comment: The third option is to do *both*.... implement both a `void HandleRequest()` and a `async Task HandleRequestAsync()` method that do the same thing (kind of like SqlCommand has both `ExecuteReader()` and `ExecuteReaderAsync()` methods). That way you can give the caller a choice, which may depend on the overall context of the application.